# call method of dialog from other activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i have problem that i cannot call dialog method from another activity, the dialog get user input into sharedprefrnces 
here my activity that i want check if theres stored sharedprefernce if not exist i want the dialog appear to get the user input and after i click ok its continue running the main activity 
here the main

```
public class main extends Activity {


private Button button;
private EditText CardNumber;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    checkid();



        }
    });
}
public void checkid(){
 File f = new File(
            "/data/data/com.example.ahmed_samir.enjaz/shared_prefs/MyPrefs.xml");
if (f.exists())
    Toast.makeText(OpreatorMobily.this, "exist:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else {


  NationalId na= new NationalId();
    na.dialogmethod();

}

}
}
```

and here my second activity of dialog

```
public class NationalId extends Activity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

final Context context = this;
private Button button;
private TextView result;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_national_id);
    dialogmethod();
    // components from main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            dialogmethod();


        }

    });

}


public   void  dialogmethod(){
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String n = userInput.getText().toString();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString(Name, n);
                            editor.commit();
                            // edit text
                            result.setText(userInput.getText());

                            Toast.makeText(NationalId.this, "saved:" + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}

}
```

Comment: `new NationalId();`... Never `new` an Activity

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this. A possible solution is to create a separate class which contains a static method for your dialog.

So in your activity you can call it like this:

```
Dialog myDialog = CustomDialog.createDialog(this); 
myDialog.show();
```

Inside the static method:

```
public static Dialog createDialog(Context context) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    //do all the initialization stuff

    //return the dialog
    return dialog;
}
```